# .htaccess Redirection [force www except index.php]

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, conditional-statements

I'm trying to do an htaccess redirection based on this condition :

Redirect all pages without "www" `http://siteweb.com` to `http://www.siteweb.com/index.html`
Except `http://siteweb.com/index.php`

The `http://siteweb.com/index.php` must to be redirected to `http://www.siteweb.com/index.php`

Actually i use this code [but something wrong on  it :s]

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule !^/index.php$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (?!^index\.php$)^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

This will redirect all URIs except `index.php` to a domain with `www`. However your question is confusing because you also wrote that:

`The http://siteweb.com/index.php must to be redirected To http://www.siteweb.com/index.php`

Which tells me that may be you want to redirect every URI including `index.php` to a domain with `www`.

Comment: Thank you four your fast reply, But for the second condition i want http://siteweb.com/index.php => http://www.siteweb.com/index.php
http://siteweb.com/* => http://siteweb.com/index.HTML

Actually your code work just for site.com => www.site.com